# How to add trailing slash to url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want that 
http://www.example.com/contact 
always gets redirected to 
http://www.example.com/contact/ 
with ending slash.

This is my current simple url rewrite setting:

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1/index.html [L]
```